# Evaluating the Expected value of a uniform distribution. How does the integral come about?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An insurance policy is written to cover a loss, $X$, where $X$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1000]$ At what level must a deductible be set in order for the expected payment to be $25$% of what it would be with no deductible?

We want to find a $D$ such that:

$X \in [0,D] \cup (D,1000]$

So:

$\frac{1}{4} 500 = \int_D^{1000} \frac{X-D}{1000}dx$

I figured since D is a constant we would treat it as such and after integrating we would get:

$\frac{x^2-x}{2000} \Big\vert_D^{1000}$

but instead it is supposed to come out as:

$\frac{(X-D)^2}{2000} \Big\vert_D^{1000}$

Why is this?

Comment: Your notation is a bit off; I'll clarify things in my answer.

Comment: You wrote:  must a deductible be set in order for the expected payment to be 25 of what    Do you mean 25%?

Comment: Yes I will correct that

Answer (score 0):

Write $Y=(X-D)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X>D\}}$, then for $0\leqslant t\leqslant 1000-D$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(Y\leqslant t,X\leqslant D) + \mathbb P(Y\leqslant t,X> D)\\
&= \mathbb P((X-D)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X>D\}}\leqslant t, X\leqslant D) + \mathbb P((X-D)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X>D\}}\leqslant t, X>D)\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant D) + \mathbb P(D<X\leqslant t+D)\\
&= \frac D{1000} + \left(\frac{t+D}{1000}\right)\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,1000-D]}(t)\\
&= \frac{t+D}{1000}.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \int_0^{1000-D} \mathbb P(Y>t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^{1000-D}  \left(1-\frac{t+D}{1000}\right)\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_D^{1000}  \left(1-\frac t{1000}\right)\mathsf dt\\
&= 1000 - \frac{(1000)^2}{2\cdot1000} - D + \frac{D^2}{2\cdot 1000}\\
&= 500 - D\left(1-\frac D{2000}\right).
\end{align}
With no deductible, the expected payment is $\mathbb E[X]=500$, and hence
$$
\mathbb E[Y]= \frac14\cdot 500 \implies 500 - D\left(1-\frac D{2000}\right) = 125\implies D=500.
$$